# Solving the 3 DOF Rotation in a simplified camera model

Tags: python, opencv, matrix, linear-algebra, camera-calibration

I'm trying to obtain a 3x3 rotation matrix and a focal length parameter in a constrained projection camera model:

formula to relate pixel coordinates to real world coordinates: 
[image]

The 3x4 matrix that describe both intrinsic and extrinsic parameters
[image]

so in my constrained camera model, u0 and v0 are set to 1, Tx, Tv, Tz are set to 0, so the DOF of this is reduced 4 DOF (3 DOF from rotation matrix + 1 DOF for the focal length (au, av)).

My problem is, although I know the rotation matrix is orthogonal and each columns / rows are related to each other so that the 3x3 matrix although have 9 elements but have only 3 DOF, I would like to know how I can get all the 9 elements of the rotational matrix and the focal length paramters (au, av) by using just 4 equations of 2 known [u,v] and [X,Y,Z] pairs.

I apologize this sounds more of a math question than a programming one, but I'm try to achieve this using numpy linear algebra solving functions. Can anyone show me any example or guide me to a direction about how I can achieve this? I have stuck on this for a few days and I don't seem to find a way accomplish this. Thanks.

Comment: Please read [ask] (esp. `Help others reproduce the problem`).

Comment: Try taking a look at a tutorial written to explain camera calibration based on Zhang's proposal, you can find the PDF file here: [link](http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~mgattass/calibration/zhang_latex/zhang.pdf). Let us know how it went after that one.